# Using javascript function at the same time with asp:Timer

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

```
<p><b> Completed: <asp:Label ID="completedPercentageLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>%</b></p>    

<script>
        function updateBar()
        {
            var bar = document.getElementById("CompletionBar");
            var width = document.getElementById("completedPercentageLabel").innerText;
            bar.style.width = width + '%';
            document.getElementById("Percentage").innerHTML = width + '%';
        }
        setInterval(updateBar, 1000);
    </script>

    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="60000"></asp:Timer>
```

I would like to ask You, how could it be possible to update my loading bar every minute, whenever Timer says to update and not have Label displayed at all. I tried finding a way to link "width" variable to asp to have it obey same rules as label, but without much success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go with `asp.net` timer control, better option will be to use update panel and perform all stuff on server side like:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <p id="CompletionBar" runat="server"></p>
        <p><b> Completed: 
          <asp:Label ID="completedPercentageLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>%
        </b></p>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="60000" OnTick="timer_tick"></asp:Timer>
```

Then on server side handler:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    completedPercentageLabel.Text = <NEW VALUE>;

    CompletionBar.Style.Add("width","<NEW VALUE>px");
}
```

More information is on [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `asp:HiddenField` to store the Progress. Then you don't have to display it.

An alternative to making your own progressbar is to use the HTML5 `progress` element. You can read more about it here:
http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_progress.asp